# We are trying to make Snowflake work AD SSO Logon using Azure AD SSO. How does Active Directory SSO work?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-private-dns

They are trying to migrate Oracle database into snowflake. THey are going to convert all existing oracle accounts to snowflake accounts. Now, if AD LDAP logon is enabled, does new users have to only be created in LDAP end, and will those be able to be tagged to accounts while conencting to snowflake? say currently there are 10 oracle accounts which was converted into 10 snowflake acccounts. If LDAP is enabled, can multiple employee IDs be added to use one of 10 snowflake account, by creating LDAP account.

Sorry if I sound dumb. I am not too experienced i LDAP/AD/admin work

Comment: Does this article answer your question?  I think you're looking for SCIM integration with AD and Snowflake:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html

Answer (score 0):

You usually have one Azure AD and need configure every snowflake account to use it. 
Which employee can access which snowflake account is controlled on the snowflake side, where you need to create a database user.

Say "Martina" needs access to Snowflake Account A and B. You need her in the Azure AD, as well as create her user in Account A and B.

You can find more details how to do this here: 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-configure-snowflake.html